# Apply a function to a column in PySpark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I'm new to Spark, PySpark to be specific. I have a dataframe that looks like

```
col_1  | col_2  | col_3
apple  | red    | 2016-01-28 00:56:55
banana | yellow | 2011-01-14 10:26:33.231
```

I've a function `convert()` that converts a datetime string like `2016-01-28 00:56:55` (may or may not have millisecond) into a float number representing UNIX time, like `1453971415`. What's the PySpark way of applying this function to my `col_3`, so all the timestamps in `col_3` are unix time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `from_unixtime` to cast the string to a timestamp and then `cast("long")` to get the `unix timestamp`

If all your timestamps end with milliseconds, you can directly use the `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"` format for conversion:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('col_3', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('col_3', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'))\
                .cast("timestamp")).withColumn('col_3', col('col_3').cast("long")).show()
```

But if you have a mix of timestamps with and without milliseconds, you can use substring to convert them into the `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` format.

```
df.withColumn('col_3', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substring(col("col_3"),0,19), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))\
                .cast("timestamp")).withColumn('col_3', col('col_3').cast("long")).show()

+------+------+----------+                                                      
| col_1| col_2|     col_3|
+------+------+----------+
| apple|   red|1453960615|
|banana|yellow|1295018793|
+------+------+----------+
```

Milliseconds can be stripped off because they don't affect the Unix timestamp.

Comment: That looks so clean!! Unfortunately it doesn't work on my data because some of the timestamps also have millisecond part. I updated my question.

Comment: I've updated my answer. `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'` can be used if you have milliseconds.